# Нужно ли тут тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "Почему волшебный — спросите вы?"
Честно говоря, заблудилась тут в знаках препинания. Как их правильно расставить, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Тире для обозначения смысловой паузы ставится при инверсии изъяснительного придаточного, например: Он приедет, но когда – не знаю. Хорошо, что они венчаются, а как жить будут – кто знает. Как рассказывал учитель – долго слушал у окна я.

Извините, пожалуйста, за неточное оформление. Я имела в виду, что знак тире выбран правильно, а дальше сразу перешла к объяснениям. Надеюсь, что автор вопроса не в претензии.

ЕЩЁ ОДИН ОТВЕТ (ДРУГОЙ, ИЗМЕНЕННЫЙ)

Предложение записываем так: Почему волшебный? – спросите вы.
Это упрощённый вариант оформления прямой речи –  средний вариант  между БСП и обычным оформлением прямой речи.

Другие варианты:

А) Вы спросите, почему он волшебный. Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, косвенный вопрос.

Б) Почему он волшебный – спросите вы. Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, косвенный вопрос, инверсия.

в) Вы спросите: почему волшебный? Это БСП, прямой вопрос.

г) «Почему волшебный?» - спросите вы. Обычная прямая речь.

Comment: А как насчет конкретного ответа на поставленный вопрос? Автор вопроса привел предложение, которое его интересует.